# cakephp 3.2 email with sendgrid issue

Tags: php, email, cakephp-3.0, sendgrid

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to send mails with sendgrid.

this is the code i currently have:

employees controller:

```
function _sendEmail($id) {
    $email = new Email();
        try {
            $email->from(['coms@me.co' => 'Me'])
                ->profile('SendGrid')
                ->to([$id['email'] => $id['full_name']])
                ->subject("TEST SUBJECT")
                ->emailFormat("both")
                ->template('default')
                ->send('My message');
            $this->Flash->success("Message sent.");
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo 'Exception : ', $ex->getMessage(), "\n";
        }                              
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

I'm working with this plugin I found a few days ago; https://github.com/Iandenh/cakephp-sendgrid... I configured everything as stated in the docs but when I want to send the mail, nothing happens, the function flashes the success message and makes the redirection, but no email is sent.

This is the email transport in the app.php

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'SendGridEmail' => [
        'className' => 'SendGridEmail.SendGrid',
        'api_key' => 'API_KEY'
    ],
```

and the delivery profile

```
'Email' => [
    'SendGrid' => [
        'transport' => 'SendGridEmail',
        'template' => 'default',
        'layout' => 'default',
        'emailFormat' => 'both',
        'from' => ['coms@me.co' => 'Me'],
        'sender' => ['coms@me.co' => 'Me'],
    ]
]
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can point me out any mistake or a possible solution for my problem.

Comment: Did you remove the API keys etc. from the configuration file before posing it here? Maybe a silly question but just making sure.

Comment: haha yes I removed it before posting.

Comment: The plugins transport seems to swallow the SendGrid API response, so you'll never know what happens to the API calls. You may want to ask the developer for an enhancement on that issue, and/or extend the transport add functionality as required. Also be sure to check out **[Webhooks](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/index.html)**, as API calls only notify about whether the API call itself was successful, not whether sending the mail was. On a side note, why don't you use the SendGrid SMTP relay?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this might be too late but in case if anyone facing the same issue.

**This is working for me**

So the first mistake you did is you are using the Email class, with sendgrid you should be using sendgrid Mail method now

I assume you have already installed this package if not go ahead and add it to the composer.json file and update composer

```
 "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~7",
```

After that you can use sendgrid class for sending emails like shown in example below

```
    protected function sendEmail($to, $subject, $content)
{
    $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
    $email->setFrom(Configure::consume('App.from_email'), Configure::consume('Theme.title'));
    $email->setSubject($subject);
    $email->addTo($to);
    $email->addContent("text/html", 'Your email body');
    $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(Configure::consume('App.sendgrid_api_key'));
    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
}
```

You need to replace **sendgrid_api_key** with your api key. I am using it from my configuration file.